# regular querystring in Zend framework controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, controller, query-string

I am using Zend framework and it does URL rewriting
but I want to handle in controller just regular querysting, get request
seomthing like this transactionsExternal.phppage=1&start=0&limit=100&sort=threadid&dir=ASC&callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback1

Can somebody tell me how to get this GET request variables in controller? considering that Zend prevents me just to use variables like $_GET[something]
 $this->getRequest()->getParams();  also  is not returning anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZF does not prevent you using `$_GET`, although doing so is discouraged. `$this->getRequest()->getParam('start')`, or `$this->getRequest()->getParams()` will give you the GET params. So if this isn't working for you something else is going wrong somewhere.

Is 'transactionsExternal.php' definitely part of your ZF app?

Comment: I am not able to get nor $_GET values nor $this->getRequest()->getParams() in my controller.                                                  
localhost/transactions/view?callback=tt  this is controller and seems like working, what else can be reason?

Comment: If localhost/transactions/view?callback=tt is a controller and works, does transactionsExternal.php go to a controller?

Comment: I mean I am able to get param when request is like this /transactions/json/id/9

Comment: but when it is like this transactions/json/?id=9 I can not get

Answer (score 0):

How are your controllers and actions set up?

Zend Framework 1 works with key/pair values for get parameters. So you might have a transaction controller and a get action. A request would look like so:

```
domain.com/transactions/get
```

To append and ID GET parameter you would do:

```
domain.com/transactions/get/id/10
```

Then In your controller action you would do the following to get the id value:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$request->getParam('id');
```

Comment: I know how zend work I just want to handle querystring not in a zend format but like regular, something like this  transactionsExternal.php?_dc=1355232398494&page=1&start=0&limit=100&sort=threadid&dir=ASC&callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback1